# Finding Lines between two characters and separate them in notepad ++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a huge text file in the following pattern

```
####
Some Question 1
answer 1
####
####
Some Question 2
answer 2
some answer 2
another answer 2
####
####
Some Question 3
answer 3
some answer 3
####
```

in my project I need to:
1. find lines between two characters and I already did it by `(####)(.+?)(####)`
2. put a question mark at the end of the first line after ####
3. put a slash before the second line and before third line

to have a result like this

```
Some Question 1 ? answer1
Some Question 2 ? answer 2 / some answer 2 / another answer 2
Some Question 3 ? answer 3 / some answer 3
```

as I mentioned I already marked the text and made 3 groups \1 & 3 #### \2 the in-between lines, how can I separate those lines and make the desired changes ?

Comment: Why do you want to do this manually with notepad? In my opinion, it would be better write a script with **bash** and **sed**, using regular expressions obviously. StackExchange is not a forum for explaining how to perform manual operations on a file, but for programming.

Comment: ... **bash** and **sed** or **awk**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to do this job outside of **notepad**, using a script launched from the command line interface.

If you have **awk** installed on your system, write the following script, say *script.awk*:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

/^####$/  { if (q != "") {
              print q a
            }
            q = "";
            a = "";
            next
          }
# other lines
          { if (q == "") { 
              q = $0 " ? " 
            } else { 
              if (a == "") { 
                a = $0; 
                next
              } else {
                a = a " / " $0 ; 
                next
              }
            }
          }
```

Assuming your input is in file *input.txt*, you can run this script from the command line issuing:

```
./script.awk input.txt
```

or:

```
awk -f script.awk input.txt
```

I assume you can work in a Unix-like environment.